# How to change ambient occlusion color with AO map?

Tags: texturing, shaders, shader-nodes, ambient-occlusion

This is my node setup. I simply want to change the color of the ambient occlusion from black to a deep red. The color ramp node ONLY affects how much AO there is. [image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

figured it out. use a diffuse bsdf node in the mix shader. [image]